# People Picker React js

Tags: sharepoint-online, people-picker, reactjs

Ok I got two questions, might be related.

1.) How can I use the following library in React using import

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="_layouts/15/clienttemplates.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="_layouts/15/clientforms.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="_layouts/15/clientpeoplepicker.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="_layouts/15/autofill.js"></script>
```

I tried this but it didnt work

```
import "_layouts/15/clienttemplates.js";
import "_layouts/15/clientforms.js";
import "_layouts/15/clientpeoplepicker.js";
import "_layouts/15/autofill.js";
```

2.) How can include a working people picker in my application. I was able to make it work in angularjs but not sure if its possible in react. This is working in Angularj but in React its complaining about SPClientPeoplePicker_InitStandaloneControlWrapper not a function. I tried replacing it with "window.SPClientPeoplePicker_InitStandaloneControlWrapper" but saying its not a function

```
var schema = {};
schema["PrincipalAccountType"] = "User";
schema["SearchPrincipalSource"] = 15;
schema["ResolvePrincipalSource"] = 1;
switch (peoplePickerElementId) {
  case "ContentAuthortxt":
    schema["AllowMultipleValues"] = true;
    break;
  default:
    schema["AllowMultipleValues"] = false;
    break;
}
schema["MaximumEntitySuggestions"] = 50;
schema["Width"] = "100%";

this.SPClientPeoplePicker_InitStandaloneControlWrapper(
  peoplePickerElementId,
  null,
  schema
);
```

Comment: Do you build SPFx solution?

Comment: Nope its not SPFx, just CEWP and js files uploaded in site assets.

Comment: When I try checking the "window.SPClientPeoplePicker_InitStandaloneControlWrapper" in the developer tool console it exist, but somehow inside my components its not visible

Comment: Here's an open-source people picker react control from SharePoint PnP: https://sharepoint.github.io/sp-dev-fx-controls-react/controls/PeoplePicker/

Comment: Hi @theChrisKent Chris :) People picker from reusable controls has a dependency on SPFx related things, that's why probably it's not valid here...